# What is the relevance of the reference to moon in Ps 81: 3-4?

Tags: psalms, chronology

We read in Psalms 81:3-4 (NRSVCE) :

> Blow the trumpet at the new moon,
> at the full moon, on our festal day.
> For it is a statute for Israel,
> an ordinance of the God of Jacob

In those days when calendars were hard to come by, the sun, moon and stars helped in reckoning of time. But followers of some religions see the moon as an indicator of auspicious time. So, one can be excused for doubting if the reference to   moon in Ps 81 , was only meant to ensure uniform time of the activity that is, blowing of the trumpet . Or, did it have some more attributes ? My question therefore is: What is the relevance of the reference to moon in Ps 81: 3-4 ?

Answer (score 3):

### Biblical data

New Moon festivals are well attested in the Bible as a joyous monthly celebration commanded by God as well as the beginning of the lunar month. Psalm 81 is only the clearest example:

- Num. 10:10 commands: "Also in the day of your gladness, in your appointed feasts, and at the beginning of your months, you shall blow the trumpets over your burnt offerings and over the sacrifices of your peace offerings; and they shall be a memorial for you before your God."
- Num. 29:6 refers to "the burnt offering with its grain offering for the New Moon... a sweet aroma, an offering made by fire to the Lord."
- 1 Sam. 20:24 says "When the New Moon had come, the king [Saul] sat down to eat the feast."
- In 2 Kings 4, when the Shunemite woman plans to visit the prophet Elisha, her husband asks: “Why are you going to him today? It is neither the New Moon nor the Sabbath.”
- In 2 Chronicles 2:4 Solomon tells King Hiram of Tyre: "I am building a temple for the name of the Lord my God, to dedicate it to Him, to burn before Him sweet incense, for the continual showbread, for the burnt offerings morning and evening, on the Sabbaths, on the New Moons, and on the set feasts of the Lord our God."
- In his vision of the ideal restored Temple, the Prophet Ezekiel says: " On the day of the New Moon [the sacrifice] shall be a young bull without blemish, six lambs, and a ram; they shall be without blemish." (46:6)
- Isaiah 66:23 predicts: "And it shall come to pass
  That from one New Moon to another,
  and from one Sabbath to another,
  all flesh shall come to worship before Me,” says the Lord.
- In Second Temple times Ezra 3:5 says "They offered the regular burnt offering, and those for New Moons and for all the appointed feasts of the Lord."

However, because the New Moon festivals were also associated with the pagan tradition of the Moon as the Queen of Heaven, these festivals were sometimes denounced by the prophets, along with other Israelite traditions, when they were corrupted. Typical of this was Hosea 2:11

```
I will also cause all her mirth to cease,
Her feast days,
Her New Moons,
Her Sabbaths—
All her appointed feasts.
```

**In the Rabbinical era**

Although the festival waned in importance once Temple sacrifices were discontinued, the Talmud preserves a [New Moon benediction](https://jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/11494-new-moon-blessing-of-the) that was pronounced in synagogue worship through the medieval period:

> "Praised be our God Almighty, King of the Universe, who created the
> heavens by His word and the stars by His command. He implanted in them
> fixed laws and times. . . . And He ordered the moon to renew itself,
> as a crown of beauty over those He sustained from childhood [Israel],
> and as a symbol that they, likewise, will be regenerated in the
> future, and will worship their Maker in His glorious kingdom. Praised
> be the Lord who reneweth the moon!"

[image: Kiddush Levana (קִדּוּשׁ לְבָנָה), the Sanctification of the Moon]

Today [Rosh Chodesh](https://www.myjewishlearning.com/article/rosh-chodesh-101/), meaning "head of the month," is still celebrated in synagogues as a minor holiday, usually announced on the Sabbath prior before the New Moon. Some congregations include special prayers to mark the renewal of the Moon. It is especially important for women, who are exempted from work on Rosh Chodesh in Orthodox congregations. Some Hasidic traditions greet the New Moon with joyous outdoor prayers and dancing.

**Thus, the New Moon festival was an important part of Israelite worship and historical Jewish tradition, not merely a convenient way to mark the months.**

Answer (score 3):

For reference, the MT of Psalm 81 verses 1-3 (exclusive of the title) is:

> הַרְנִינוּ לֵאלֹהִים עוּזֵּנוּ הָרִיעוּ לֵאלֹהֵי יַעֲקֹב
> שְׂאוּ זִמְרָה וּתְנוּ תֹף כִּנּוֹר נָעִים עִם נָבֶל
> תִּקְעוּ בַחֹדֶשׁ שׁוֹפָר בַּכֵּסֶה לְיוֹם חַגֵּנוּ

So Psalm 81:1-2 uses **three** different words for singing,

1. הרנינו (*harninu*), "sing"
2. הריעו (*hari'u*), "shout"
3. זמרה (*zimrah*), "melody"

plus **one homonym** for song, עוזנו (*uzaynu*), which in this context means "our strength".

This usage of multiple references is a common emphatic form in Psalms and is meant to indicate **all** forms of song. See in particular Psalm 148.

Psalm 81:2-3 reference **five** musical instruments:

1. תף (*tof*), drum
2. כינור נעים (*kinor na'im*), a type of stringed instrument
3. נבל (*nevel*), another type of stringed instrument
4. שופר (*shofar*), ram's horn
5. חצצרה (*hatsatsrah*), trumpet, which is not explicitly used but which is implied by the use of בכסה (*ba'keseh*) on the new moon, when trumpets were blown as commanded in Numbers 10:10

Again, the intent is to indicate **all** sorts of musical instruments.

Verse 3 also references **three** different holidays:

1. חודש (*chodesh*), "Month", refers to the New Year festival when the ram's horn was blown
2. בכסה (*ba'keseh*), "on the covering", refers to the new moon, when most of the moon is "covered"
3. יום חגינו (*yom hagenu*), "our holiday", likely refers to the feast of Tabernacles when trumpets were also blown as per Number 10:10

So the correct translation of the verse into English is

> Blow the ram's horn on the [seventh] Month, [the trumpet] on the new moon, [and on] our holiday (Tabernacles).

This condensed style of writing is another hallmark of Psalms in particular and song lyrics in general in all times and languages. See for example Psalm 48:2.

So, the reference is not specifically to the moon in verse 3, but to three different  festivals and therefore to **all** the festivals in general, on which blowing either ram's horns or trumpets was ordained. This provides the thematic bridge from the singing to the musical instruments and then to the festivals.

Verse 4 provides the thematic tie from the festivals to the giving of the Law, in which the festivals are ordained, and from there to the deliverance from Egyptian servitude and the to the rest of the Psalm.

Answer (score 2):

In the Enduring Word Commentary, they have many useful notes.

See https://enduringword.com/bible-commentary/psalm-81/

The commentary suggests that the Psalm is about the Feast of Tabernacles:

> “This powerful psalm leaves no doubt of its festal character, and
> little doubt of the particular feast it was designed to serve: in all
> probability the Feast of Tabernacles. This commemorated the wilderness
> journey, and included a public reading of the law.” (Derek Kidner)

They go on to cite Numbers 10:3:

> "Also in the day of your gladness, in your appointed feasts, and at
> the beginning of your months, you shall blow the trumpets over your
> burnt offerings and over the sacrifices of your peace offerings; and
> they shall be a memorial for you before your God: I [am] the LORD your
> God."

Israel held to a lunar calendar, so references to the moon are often time references. For example, Ecclesiastes 3 has a list of twenty-eight times; a sidereal month has 27.32 days, so twenty-eight implies rounding up.

They can have symbolic meanings as well. In Joseph's dream, the sun, moon and eleven stars bowed down to him. Some think that these symbolize his family (father, mother, and brothers) but there is a problem with this. Joseph later bowed before his father (not the other way around), and his mother died before his release from prison. It is likely that the sun. moon and stars bowing before him indicate his mastery over time - his knowledge of the future times of plenty and famine made him powerful. The eleven stars may have been the estimated eleven years he spent in prison, or the eleven decades of his life (he lived to 110). Thus references to the sun, moon and stars can refer to God's wisdom, for only God knows the future.

Answer (score 1):

> And God said, Let there be lights in the firmament of the heaven to divide the day from the night; and let them be for signs, and for seasons, and for days, and years
> And God made two great lights; the greater light to rule the day, and the lesser light to rule the night …
> — Genesis 1:14,16

Every 29 days, 12 hours, 44 minutes, 3⅓ seconds the Moon goes through its 19 year metonic cycle, which consists of 19×12 months plus 7 leap months.
These 235 lunar months almost exactly match 19 solar years.

God created the Moon to serve as a calendar.

(It's perhaps a coincidence, but having 7 leap years out of 19 in the calendar nicely matches the 7 holy days within the 19 days of God's festivals.)

---

The Bible commands 3 holy days in the Spring and 4 holy days in the Autumn, using the Moon to define when each month begins:

> These are the feasts of the LORD, even holy convocations, which ye shall proclaim in their seasons.
> — Leviticus 23:4

Passover:

> In the fourteenth day of the first month at even is the LORD'S passover.
> — Leviticus 23:5

Feast of Unleavened Bread:

> And on the fifteenth day of the same month is the feast of unleavened bread unto the LORD: seven days ye must eat unleavened bread.
> In the first day ye shall have an holy convocation: ye shall do no servile work therein.
> But ye shall offer an offering made by fire unto the LORD seven days: in the seventh day is an holy convocation: ye shall do no servile work therein.
> — Leviticus 23:6–8

Pentecost:

> And ye shall count unto you from the morrow after the sabbath [*the weekly sabbath that occurs during the Feast of Unleavened Bread*], from the day that ye brought the sheaf of the wave offering; seven sabbaths shall be complete:
> Even unto the morrow after the seventh sabbath shall ye number fifty days; and ye shall offer a new meat offering unto the LORD.
> — Leviticus 23:15,16

The Feast of Trumpets:

> … In the seventh month, in the first day of the month, shall ye have a sabbath, a memorial of blowing of trumpets, an holy convocation.
> — Leviticus 23:24

The Day of Atonement:

> … on the tenth day of this seventh month there shall be a day of atonement: it shall be an holy convocation unto you …
> — Leviticus 23:27

The Feast of Tabernacles:

> … The fifteenth day of this seventh month shall be the feast of tabernacles for seven days unto the LORD.
> — Leviticus 23:34

The Last Great Day:

> … Also in the fifteenth day of the seventh month, … ye shall keep a feast unto the LORD seven days: on the first day shall be a sabbath, and on the eighth day shall be a sabbath.
> — Leviticus 23:39

---

Numbers 10;10 does say "*… in the beginnings of your months, ye shall blow with the trumpets over your burnt offerings …*", but this seems
to be a smaller more private monthly event than would be associated with a "*festal day*" for the nation.
The Feast of Trumpets is the only festival that explicitly requires that trumpets be blown at the new moon.
So it is likely that this "blowing of trumpets" at the Feast of Trumpets corresponds to the psalm's first line: "*Blow the trumpet at the new moon*".

The fifteenth day of the month occurs at a full moon, so the first day of the Feast of Tabernacles corresponds to the psalm's "festal day" in its second line: "*at the full moon, on our festal day*".

The two holy days mentioned were two of the seven days God declared as holy, as confirmed by the last two lines: "*For it is a statute for Israel, an ordinance of the God of Jacob*".

The only significance of the reference to the moon is that it defines when a new calendar month begins.
Attributing any other significance would be the equivalent of people today today thinking that events in March or July are somehow related to the planet Mars or Julius Cæsar.

Comment: Sorry... I need to downvote this. See Num 10:10 for the commandment to blow trumpets to celebrate each new moon. This is the "ordinance" referred to in the Psalm. See my answer for ample evidence that the new moon celebration was also a festal day.

Comment: also note the Talmudic prayer which attributes additional significance to the New Moon beyond calendar-keeping: "And He ordered the moon to renew itself, as a crown of beauty over those He sustained from childhood... praise the Lord who reneweth the moon. "

Comment: @DanFefferman Numbers 10:10 commands blowing חֲצֹצְרֹת, this verse calls to blow the שׁוֹפָר , the two aren't the same. Please reconsider your downvote.

Comment: @AbuMunirIbnIbrahimalYahud, just to confuse things further, Leviticus 23:24 used the word תְּרוּעָה for the Feast of Trumpets.

Comment: @AbuMunirIbnIbrahimalYahud, speaking of שׁוֹפָר, in case you're not aware of this coincidence, you might appreciate my answer to [What are two languages, that share similarities, that you find surprising? - Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-are-two-languages-that-share-similarities-that-you-find-surprising/answer/Ray-Butterworth).

Comment: My main problem with @RayButterworth's answer has to do with his argument that the New Moon was not instituted by an ordinance, but Num 10.10 and others show the opposite.

Comment: @DanFefferman says "*the New Moon was not instituted by an ordinance*". I'm not sure what that means.  ¶ I think my main argument is that the Feast of Tabernacles is the only feast that starts with a *full* moon.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity. I understood you to be arguing that the New Moon festivals were not instituted by a commandment/ordinance in the Torah. But Num. 10.10 includes them, and Num. 29:6 refers to "the burnt offering with its grain offering for the New Moon." Several prophets also speak of it as a sacrificial feast day -- so that while not one of the "set feasts" (yearly) these celebrations were important in and of themselves, not only as markers of the new month.

Comment: I tried to remove my downvote on the grounds that even though I disagree with answer, it provides useful research. Got a message that the vote is locked until it is edited.

Comment: @DanFefferman, I've now mentioned Numbers 10:10. (And just because my answer disagrees with your answer, it doesn't mean I think yours is wrong.)